# Is it necessary to shut off the water in order to tighten a handle on a Moen faucet?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom

I have a Moen faucet. The handle unscrews.

Do I need to shut off the water to remove the barrel shape under the handle in order to tighten the handle?

Comment: A picture would come in handy.

Comment: Please read added comment to post thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you're trying to do is tighten a loose handle - the answer is no - you don't have to shut off the water. The screw to the handle should be on top of the handle. Sometime it's under a cap which is usually just pressed in to the handle. Pry it off with a blade of some type and tighten the screw.
That should do it unless you have a setup that's totally different than most Moen faucet handles. In that case - send a picture.

Comment: There are no caps on the handles or screws the handle is tightened from underneath, from what i can tell the barrel under the handle untightens from the faucet and the barrel and handle come off together off of the top of the valve. I just dont want to loosen the barrel and have the valve pop out shooting water to the ceiling. I dont want to shut off water if I dont have too.

Comment: You just unscrew the handle but you should also be able to tighten the barrel and handle by turning it. Also understand you don't have to turn off water for the entire house just at the shutoff that should be under your sink.